# Browser is not setting Cookie from response header after fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http-post, fetch-api

Trying to implement fetch request for a login page but not browser  not setting the cookies received from the response

```
login(user, pass) {
    console.log("from login=", user)
    var data = { "username": user, "password": pass };
    var url = '***************************************';
    //console.log(data)
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(data), //just pass the instance
        crossDomain: true,
        credentials: 'same-origin'
    }).then((res) => { var head = res.headers; console.log("Headeers", head.get("Cookie")); return res.json(); });
}
```

The Request headers as in the chrome dev tools are

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:57
content-type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Host:www.buynsta.com
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Referer:http://localhost:3000/login
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers as in the chrome dev tools are

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-              check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:261
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 07 Jun 2017 05:37:25 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Set-Cookie:frontend=ajtcpi320jis092dkv75abllq0; expires=Sat, 17-Jun-2017 05:37:26 GMT; Max-Age=864000; path=/; domain=www.buynsta.com
Set-Cookie:persistent_shopping_cart=deleted; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT; Max-Age=0; path=/; domain=www.buynsta.com
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.6.24
```

Comment: is the request "same origin" - hint 1: `localhost:3000` and `www.buynsta.com` is not the same ... hint 2: `credentials: 'same-origin'`

Comment: @JaromandaX I have alraedy done hint 2

Comment: I have alraedy done hint 2 do you have anyway for me to to bypass hint1

Comment: you've DONE that hint? my hint was to identify the PROBLEM not the SOLUTION ...  "same-origin" ... but the request is **not** same origin is it ... try changing "same-origin" to "include" (I tried to get you to do some basic research, but clearly failed)

Comment: Ya thank you, sir, I'm a beginner at this so I did quite a bit of research about it but was not able to get it 
and I also tried your second suggestion and it gave this error
when I changed  "same-origin" to "include" any help

    Fetch API cannot load http://www.buynsta.com/kbrest/customer/login?v=2.0.3. The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: I think that error speaks for itself - perhaps buynsta don't want you accessing their resources like you are trying to, or perhaps they don't know how to issue CORS headers correctly - short version, buynsta need to issue correct headers for CORS, nothing you can do on client side

Comment: @JaromandaX Sir so what do you suggest should be the suitable CORS header that buynsta need to take care off 
wt should the value of this be 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: The error message has the answer

Comment: @JaromandaX Thankyou sir fixed it by changing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin on the server but why isnt the same error comming when i use the same code in react-native it seems to be working fine there , am I missing out on something here?

Comment: perhaps because native apps are not browsers